# Can't upload .ipa from Xcode 11 - "The Info.plist indicates an iOS app, but submitting a pkg or mpkg"

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, ipa

I have an ios app in flutter and trying to submit app to apple store using Xcode. But getting below error while it starts uploading.

*"The Info.plist indicates an iOS app, but submitting a pkg or mpkg"*

As per other suggestions, I have checked my minimum version in info.plist and it's 13.

I have also tried to export file but it's not exporting only .ipa file now and exporting multiple files in a folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue commonly caused by **LSMinimumSystemVersion**. You should remove it from the Info.plist inside of your app. That value is for *macOS* only.

If that's not the case, then just create a new dummy Xcode project and compare its Info.plist to the one in your project. So, you can notice something unusual.